# Is there any python support for creating a custom costmap_2d layer?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to make my custom costmap_2d layer from pointcloud2 data, which would be marked as free space.
I looked at the tutorial, which is in C++. I was wondering if there is any other support in python for the same. It would make it a lot easier in python, I think.

Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344276/is-there-any-python-support-for-creating-a-custom-costmap_2d-layer?/) by [ShyamGanatra](https://answers.ros.org/users/38099/shyamganatra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No.

Not in the standard packages.

The navstack uses C++ plugins to host layer plugins. This is not supported by / with Python.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-16**:
Some related Q&As: #q11521 and #q174067.

I don't believe anything has changed.

Using `boost::python` or possible `pybind11` ([docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html)) would appear to be the way to do this, if you're still interested.